# Is there a [ci skip] option in GitLab CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, build-pipeline

I'm debugging the use of a report creator. I forgot a line and would like to edit the code without triggering the build pipeline.

I know that it's possible to write [ci skip] in the commit pipeline to pass the pipeline execution in Jenkins CI, but I'm using GitLab CI.

Does the same mechanism exist for GitLab CI? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skipping-jobs

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, there is:

> If your commit message contains `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]`, using any capitalization, the commit will be created but the pipeline will be skipped.
>
> Alternatively, one can pass the `ci.skip` [Git push option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--oltoptiongt) if using Git 2.10 or newer:
>
> ```
> git push -o ci.skip
> ```

From: [GitLab CI Pipelines documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#skip-a-pipeline) - "Skip Pipeline"

Comment: Take a look at the full list of [push command options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd)

Comment: Apparently, also any kind of case works, for example taco case `[skip-ci]`